# Open file on none default application (browser)

Tags: actionscript, air

How do you check what is the default browser to open a html file, and open it with another browser? I'm having security issues on Chrome locally, but luckily the application I'm creating allowed me to run an air application 1st. So I am wondering could there be any work around for me to open the file in other browser other than Chrome?

Comment: By file, you mean a local HTML page or what exactly ? And your app is it an AIR app ( from where you want to open the browser ) ? When you got a security error in chrome, who told you that you will not get the same error in other browsers ? And, could you explain more the situation, an AIR app will open a file in the browser ... ?

Comment: Basically the air will do some other stuff, and open a html file in a browser. The security restriction only happened in Chrome (Externalinterface.call), cause tested on IE and FireFox its fine. Something to do with Chrome pre-installed flash player version

Comment: If you give us the exact error with your code ( if possible ), we will try to find a solution for that, knowing that with AIR you can run another browser instead of chrome, if you want.